# delegate protocol for two viewcontrollers

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

i am fairly new to ios programming and i am not sure what the best way to do this is. i want to Create a delegate protocol that can be used to notify interested observers (two viewcontrollers to be specific) of an image array's change in state. i want each view controller to conform to it also. for example, if it is in state 1 then it only appears in the first viewcontroller and if it is in state 2 then it only appears in the second viewcontroller.
this is what i have so far:

```
protocol imgState {

   static var state1 : Int {get set}
   static var state2 : Int {get set}


func stateChange(){

if state1 == 1 {

    set {
            state1 == 0
            state2 == 1

        }

    }
if state2 == 1 {

    set {
        state1 == 1
        state2 == 0 

}
    }

}
}
```

my thinking is to call the function in each viewcontroller when a button is pressed to change the state.

is there any good tutorials someone could direct me towards or any guidance on how to start at all? anything should help.

Answer (score 1):

I've used delegates in the past but I much prefer posting a notification. 
In your example, when the button is pressed, you can do something like this,

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("buttonPressed", object: nil)
```

The other views would listen for this notification with:

```
// Usually added to viewDidLoad()    
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "updateState", name: "buttonPressed", object: nil)
```

You would then have a func named "updateState" in the relevant view controllers which would be called whenever the 'buttonPressed' notification is posted.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this in a much simpler way using NSNotifications... The way you would do it, since you're trying to listen to 2 different inputs/actions, is to post a notification for each... these will respond right away!

So as an example, in an action method (but could be used anywhere really) we could be expecting 2 different values...

```
var var1:Bool = false // setting a false value as a default


@IBAction func expectAction(sender:AnyObject) {
    if var1 == false {
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("key1", object: nil)
    } else {
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificatioinName("key2", object: nil)
    }

}
```

Then on each of your classes you would add observers to respond to such notifications as follows:
(assuming ViewController1 is listener 1 and ViewController2 is listener 2)

At your viewDidLoad() method in ViewController1 add the following:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector:"actonKey1:", name:"key1", object: nil)
```

Then add a new method in ViewController1

```
@obj private func actonKey1(notification: NSNotification) {
    // do your work here
}
```

Finally (for this ViewController1) add a deinitializing method like this:

```
deinit{
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
}
```

You repeat this for ViewController2 changing the appropriate names of the key1 to key2

At your viewDidLoad() method in ViewController2 add the following:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector:"actonKey2:", name:"key2", object: nil)
```

Then add a new method in ViewController2

```
@obj private func actonKey2(notification: NSNotification) {
    // do your work here
}
```

Finally (for this ViewController2) add a deinitializing method like this:

```
deinit{
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
}
```

And that's pretty much it... The response time is amazingly fast... and it is (at least to my belief) less convoluted than using protocols and delegates...

Cheers

Comment: okay did everything you said. but im still not sure how to tell the viewcontroller whether or not to display each image.

Comment: Your initial request was to determine the state of an image and notifying each view controller of such change...  create a variable, which keeps track of every time you are programmatically modifying the image yourself... that way  in each view controller when you have the condition to identify the state of the image, it will display such image...

Answer (score 0):

One idea is to use an Observable/Subject class (like this one that I wrote: https://gist.github.com/dtartaglia/0a71423c578f2bf3b15c but there are lots of libraries that provide this, and other, services.)

With this service, you would wrap the image in a `Subject` object and the two view controllers would `attach` a block of code to the subject. Then whenever the contained image is changed (by assigning to `mySubject.value`) the attached blocks will be called.

Just be sure to `dispose` of the observers when done.